# NSDictionary order does not match allKeys order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I've created NSDictionary of sorted arrays by name organized by first letter (see results below).  When I use the command allKeys for that same Dictionary, the order is not the same.  I need the order the same because this NSDictionary is used in UITableview and should be alphabetical.

```
 - (NSDictionary*) dictionaryNames {

NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSMutableArray *objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *letters = self.exhibitorFirstLetter;
NSArray *names = self.exhibitorName;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.exhibitorFirstLetter count]; i++)
{
    [objects addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
}

dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys:letters];

for (NSString *name in names) { 
    NSString *firstLetter = [name substringToIndex:1];

    for (NSString *letter in letters) {  //z, b
        if ([firstLetter isEqualToString:letter]) {
            NSMutableArray *currentObjects = [dictionary objectForKey:letter];
            [currentObjects addObject:name];
        }
    }

}

    NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys]);
return dictionary;
```

}

```
 B =     (
    "Baker's Drilling",
    "Brown Drilling"
);
C =     (
    "Casper Drilling"
);
J =     (
    "J's, LLC"
);
N =     (
    "Nelson Cleaning",
    "North's Drilling"
);
T =     (
    "Tim's Trucks"
);
Z =     (
    "Zach's Main",
    "Zeb's Service",
    "Zen's"
);
```

}

```
J,
T,
B,
N,
Z,
C
```

)

Comment: That's because NSDictionary keys are not ordered. If you want them ordered, put them in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is NSDictionary key order guaranteed the same as initialized if it never changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496430/is-nsdictionary-key-order-guaranteed-the-same-as-initialized-if-it-never-changes), [NSDictionary allKeys -- does it always return the same order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9575387), [NSDictionary allKeys order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17745212)

Answer (score 4):

NSDictionary is not an ordered collection. There's no way to control how it orders things, and it may change completely depending on OS version, device type, and dictionary contents.

Answer (score 1):

I just put the NSDictionary in sorted array:

```
- (NSArray*)sortAllKeys:(NSArray*)passedArray{
    NSArray* performSortOnKeys = [passedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    return performSortOnKeys;
}
```